# Remote SSH with VS Code not finding hosts' python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, remote-server

The context is as follows:

- I have a PC with a python installation (and some libraries)
- I have a laptop with another python installation

When I use VS Code (on the laptop) to ssh into the server (the PC) and open a jupyter notebook, I can find the laptop's Python environment, but not the PC's python environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are running on each?

Comment: Both are windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh) to creat connection.

When you have finished connecting, you can use the shortcut **"ctrl+shift+P"** and type **"Python: select interpreter"** to choose the python environment.

Comment: Should install Python (Intellisense) from Microsoft first.